# No connection between devices in local network

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, gateway, dnsmasq

I have home server that also works as router (gateway). It has 2 interfaces one for internet (`enp4s0`) and another (`enp4s1`) looks into local network. All devices from local network uses internet from `enp4s0` (setup via `masquerading` and `dnsmasq`) and it works fine, but I can't ping any device inside LAN from gateway, the only device I can ping from devices in LAN is gateway. Also there is port forwarding, that works well (I can access devices in LAN which ports were forwarded, but only from remote host). What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my configuration:

```
smt-server ~ # iptables-save
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3059:171583]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2567:132938]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -d X.X.X.X/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [372724122:553710820064]
:INPUT ACCEPT [365684276:547976820091]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [7037750:5732930849]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [193052833:10399179735]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [200090538:16132105927]
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2775:188343]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2604:109020]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i enp4s1 -o enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/24 -o enp4s1 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

smt-server ~ # ip ro list
default via X.X.X.X dev enp4s0  metric 204
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp4s1  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.151.102  metric 205
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
X.X.X.X/24 dev enp4s0  proto kernel  scope link  src X.X.X.X  metric 204
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp4s1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1

smt-server ~ # ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:80:48:28:1e:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:e5:49:e4:43:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:d3:9a:af:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp4s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:cc:18:e8:c6:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:16:6c:f2:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

smt-server ~ # ip add list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:80:48:28:1e:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::91f4:69a4:2375:9e71/64 scope link tentative
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:e5:49:e4:43:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::59e:56ea:7de3:cd5e/64 scope link tentative
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:d3:9a:af:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet X.X.X.X/24 brd X.X.X.X scope global enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5c50:880a:b7ba:7b38/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: enp4s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:cc:18:e8:c6:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 scope global enp4s1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.151.102/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global enp4s1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f987:2ed0:61ed:ddaf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:16:6c:f2:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ee83:8058:deee:dd8c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

smt-server ~ # sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1

smt-server ~ # cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
interface=enp4s1
dhcp-range=192.168.0.100,192.168.0.250,72h

smt-server ~ # netstat -rna
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         X.X.X.X         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enp4s1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
X.X.X.X         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp4s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp4s1
```

To prevent questions "Are you stupid? You're really trying to access devices behind NAT?" - Nope, I'm trying to access device which can be accessed via DMZ.

Also I have 3 more empty ethernet-ports in server and I wonder is it possible to connect all of them in one LAN? (This is not so important, but anyway it would be really good to use this feature)

UPD: here is script with which I configure my LAN:

```
#!/bin/bash

source="enp4s0"

targets="enp4s1"

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 &> /dev/null
sysctl -p &> /dev/null

iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -F FORWARD

for iface in $targets; do
    ip addr add 192.168.0.1/24 dev $iface &> /dev/null
    iptables -A FORWARD -i $iface -o $source -j ACCEPT &> /dev/null
done

iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT &> /dev/null
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING &> /dev/null
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $source -j MASQUERADE &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more details like what is ip scheme for your local devices. is it 192.168 or 172.17
what are the ip addresses of both interface facing internet and LAN.

Comment: @FaisalSaleem, enp4s0 (X.X.X.X) - internet, enp4s1 (192.168.0.1) - LAN. 192.168.0.217 - IP of client

Answer (score 0):

Please check if network mask and broadcast are configured properly on clients - its should match parametres on gw. Another tought - if you are using managed switch on the LAN - check if something like private vlan is not enabled on it.

Comment: Hm, seems like i have wrong broadcast address on gw `0.0.0.0`, on client it is `192.168.0.255`, so what should I do?

Comment: on gw set broadcast address 192.168.0.255

Comment: Anyway - while clients on lan have correct network mask and broadcast addresses they should be available mutually whithout using of gateway.

Comment: How can I change it without putting interface down or is it possible at all?

Comment: Only if you are logged in through another interface - you will cutoff yourself otherwise. If it is a production machine - you could edit a config and schedule a reboot to midnight for example. Or - login by ssh using WAN ip address and reconfigure interface like this:

Comment: Anyway - you should remove old address and add new, so there will be a small outage.

Comment: OK, I've tried: changing my script (line with iproute) to `ip route add ... broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev ...` with reenabling of interface, manually set broadcast via `ifconfig enp4s0 broadcast 192.168.0.255` and nothing works, still have `0.0.0.0` as broadcast address, so what am I doing wrong?